# Why is my array not printing in 2d?

Tags: java, arrays

```
  rowsTotal = new double[rows];
  positions = new double [rows][];

  for(index = 0; index < rows; index++){
      System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(index+65) + " : ");
      pos = keyboard.nextInt();
      if(pos > MAX_POSITIONS){
          System.out.print("ERROR: Out of range, try again: ");
          pos = keyboard.nextInt();
      }
      positions[index] = new double[pos];


      }


  System.out.print("(A)dd, (R)emove, (P)rint,          e(X)it : ");
  input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
  input = Character.toUpperCase(input);


  if(input == 'P'){
      for(int index1= 0; index1 < rows; index1++){
          for(int pos1= 0; pos1 < pos; pos1++){

              System.out.print(positions[index1][pos1] + " "); 
          }



  }

  }
```

I want the output to show it as a matrix for each row, so for the first row, it would be the values for row A, and the second row would be the values for row B, etc etc

But its outputting it all in the same row like:

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

rather than

0.0 0.0 (row A)

0.0 0.0 (row B)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the newline after each row.

```
for(int index1 = 0; index1 < rows; index1++)
{
    for(int pos1 = 0; pos1 < pos; pos1++)
    {
        System.out.print(positions[index1][pos1] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); // <-- This one!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, add a line break with

```
System.out.println("");
```

after the innermost for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
System.out.println("");
```

at the end of your first loop.

Comment: @NickP Glad that helped. Remember that you can upvote an answer which you think is helpful, or even accept the one, you think, solved your problem.

Comment: I would love to upvote an answer but it requires 15 reputation points.